# Cancel maven exclusions from parent project in child project

Tags: java, maven

I have the following in my `pom`

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.13</version>
        <!-- <scope>compile</scope>-->
    </dependency>       
    </dependencies>

    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.13</version>
        <!-- <scope>compile</scope>-->
    </dependency>
```

Basically, I want to include `slf4j-log4j12` as a dependency. However, when I do `mvn clean install`, I get the following error:

```
[INFO] log4j:log4j:jar was excluded in DepMgt, but version 1.2.17 has been found in the dependency tree.
[INFO] org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar was excluded in DepMgt, but version 1.7.13 has been found in the dependency tree.


[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:analyze-dep-mgt (analyze-dependency) on project my-project: Found Dependency errors. -> [Help 1]
```

This library seems to have been excluded in the parent project. Is there a way to cancel the exclusion and include it in this project?

#### EDIT

I tried adding this

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>
                            analyze-dep-mgt
                            </goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

But I still get the same error.

#### EDIT2

I could make it work by using this

```
<properties>
    <analyze.dependency.skip>true</analyze.dependency.skip>
    </properties>
```

But, is it possible for skip for my dependency only.

Comment: Could you try after removing the version tag from the later block of dependency(the one outside of dependencyManagement).

Comment: I tried that, but I get the same error.

Comment: Its not an error. Its just an INFO log. Also to second *org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar was excluded in DepMgt* could  you share the `DepMgt` pom.xml please

Comment: Actually, if I remove it from the dependency list, it gets successfully built. Not sure, if that is actually not a problem. Sorry, I don't have access to the parent pom.

Comment: You _can_ download the parent pom. Otherwise it would not be possible to build your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parent pom includes the following plugin

```
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:analyze-dep-mgt
```

This checks the consistency in the dependencies (You can look it up by downloading the parent pom).

Declare the plugin again and set `<skip>` to `true` to avoid this check.

Alternatively: If your parent pom defines a property which you can set to skip the execution, set this property to false.

Comment: I tried doing this ( check edit in the question), but I still get the same error.

Comment: Maybe your configuration is overridden by pluginManagement. Try to add your configuration to pluginManagement.

Comment: I could do it successfully by doing this `<properties>
 <analyze.dependency.skip>true</analyze.dependency.skip>
 </properties>`. But, is it possible to skip for my dependency only?

Comment: I cannot find a parameter for that.

Comment: Thanks, if you can just edit your answer, I will accept it as an answer to this post.

Comment: I had the same error and this didn't seem to fix it. Then I saw that I used version 2.6 - **As soon as I raised that to 2.10 it worked** (with your solution)